# Store class type as property when initializing class

Tags: swift, generics

I was wondering if I could pass a Type that conforms to a protocol in the init of my class and save that type as a property so I can use it on another function of my class.

I think that I would be able to pass this generic type in my `run` function but i would prefer no to do that.

```
protocol example {
    static func exampleFunc()
}


class MyClass {

    init(type: TypeThatConformsToExampleProtocol) {
        // can i save `type` as a property and use it in my `run` function to call exampleFunc ?
    }

    func run() {
        type.exampleFunc()
    } 
}
```

EDIT: I have edited the protocol and made the method `static` i forgot to add it earlier.

Comment: In your example, `exampleFunc()` is an instance method, not a static method, so you couldn't call it on the type itself. Did you mean to make it static? Or did you mean to pass a value rather than a type?

Comment: @RobNapier Yes I meant static, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things in your question.  The thing you ask, storing a type, and the thing you do with that type in the code you provide.

#### Can you store the type?

Yes.  But you have to make `MyClass` generic.

```swift
class MyClass<T: example> {

    let type: T.Type
    
    init(type: T.Type) {
        self.type = type
    }
}
```

There's nothing to be gained from doing this, because your class will be specialized on type `T` so you could just refer to `T`.  You don't need to store it.

You could make a generic initializer instead of making the class generic, and then cast the type to `as Any` (or maybe it's `AnyType` - I forget), then in your example cast it to `as example.self`.  There isn't anything useful you can do with it though.

#### How to do what your example code tries to do

Your example code won't work in any case, because `exampleFunc` is an instance method, so you need an instance of the type not the type itself.

Fortunately there is a way to do what you your code seems to want to do, and its made easier by the fact that your example protocol doesn't have `Self` or `associatedtype` constraints.

```swift
class MyClass {

    let exampleInstance: example
    
    init(_ exampleInstance: example) {
        self.exampleInstance = exampleInstance
    }

    func run() {
        exampleInstance.exampleFunc()
    }
}
```

#### What about `static` methods?

The natural follow-up question might be, "OK, so could I do the same thing with a static method of the protocol?".  The answer is yes, but slightly differently.  First modify the protocol to require conforming types to have a static method:

```swift
protocol example 
{
    func exampleFunc()
    static func staticRun()
}
```

There are two ways (and maybe more than don't come to mind immediately).  The first is to going back to making your class generic.  If you do that, you don't even need an initializer:

```swift
class MyClass<T: example>
{
    func run() {
        T.staticRun()
    }
}
```

The second way moves the generic part to the initializer instead of the `class`.  In that case you, you store a closure:

```swift
class MyClass
{
    let runClosure: () -> Void

    init<T: example>(type: T.Type) {
        self.runClosure = { T.staticRun() }
    }

    func run() {
        runClosure()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what if the method defined in the protocol was `static`. I forgot to specify it was static im sorry.

Comment: I handle that case later run my answer. :-)

Comment: Excellent, thats what i was looking for :)